# I can't get xdebug working

Tags: php, windows, xampp, xdebug

My system:

```
-windows 7 
- php 5.5.9
- stack:  xampp(32bit)
```

xdebug version: PHP 5.5 VC9 (32 bit) from http://xdebug.org/download.php

and my php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="php_xdebug-2.3.1-5.5-vc9-nts.dll"
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

my php installation is in: C:\xampp\php\ext

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar setup and here is what works for me:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\xdebug_log"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

Comment: Worked for me, I'm not worried what I was missing but there must have been something! :)

Answer (score 0):

i also had to struggle for 2 days after that got it working....
my config is -

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\Program Files\PHP54\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.1-5.4-vc9.dll
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```